# how can I define a specil struct by factory girl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

Using RSpec and Factory Girl, I create a factory like this:

```
factory :hot_type do
          ad_type_id 4
          city_id 110000
          image   "111"
          content { :link_url => 'xxx', :link_title => 'xxx', :count => 11 } 
end
```

when I ran the rspec, it happened an error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '}'
      content { :link_url => 'xx', :link_title => '1xx', :count => 11 }
```

How can I define the right struct?

Comment: What is the data type of "content" in the model?

Comment: Please check the data type of variable 'content' that you have mentioned. I think there is any of mapping hash to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby interprets `space + {}` as a block. You need you specify the hash as arguments explicitly. Just use brackets around it.

`content({ :link_url => 'xx', :link_title => '1xx', :count => 11 })`